# when converting uint/int to numbers what format should i use ? Little endian or LSB & MSB?

Tags: javascript, int, endianness, uint

I'm trying to convert values of integers and unsigned integers to numbers and would like to know what format to use. I am a little confused and would like some clarification.

when converting int to a number do i use little endian format or LSB&MSB format?

the same with uint....do i convert uint using the little endian format or LSB&MSB?

could you also state the reason for the choice. any help is much appreciated. Thanks. Below are the two different functions to convert bytes to numbers. what are the main differences between them? in what case would you use one over the other?

```
export function convertFromLittleEndianByteToNumber(byteArray) {
  if (!(byteArray && byteArray.length)) {
    return;
  }
  let value = 0;
  for (var i = byteArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    value = value * 256 + byteArray[i];
  }
  return value;
}


export function convertFromLSBandMSBToNumber(byteArray) {
  if (!(byteArray && byteArray.length)) {
    return;
  }
  const [LSM, MSB] = byteArray;
  let converted = (LSM | (MSB << 8)) & 0xffff;
  if (converted > MAX_POSITIVE_VALUE) {
    converted = converted - MAX_16_BIT;
  }
  return converted;
}
```

Comment: You use the bytes of an object when you want to show the contents of memory. You use the value an object represents when you want to show its value.

Comment: This is not C, and you are confused as to what "hex" is...Hexadecimal is a *text* representation of a number, and as such it is unambiguous as to meaning and you shouldn't need to know anything about endianness to convert. Whatever kind of data your "byteArray" inputs are, they aren't hex.